# Annyang addCommands

Tags: javascript, arrays, annyang

I want to make [annyang](https://github.com/TalAter/annyang) smarter. So i decide to add Commands with the help of users.

for reminders annyang commands are init like this :

```
var commands = {"your speech":yourFunction}
annyang.addCommands(commands);
```

With a form I retrive what the user wanted to say and the function associated.

```
speech = "my speech";
myfunction = "mySuperFunction";
```

but when i want to add this function like :

```
newCommand={speech:myfunction};
annyang.addCommands(newCommand);
```

Annyang says : Command successfully loaded: speech

when i debug newCommand i get : Object {speech: "mySuperFunction"}

See the problem ? JS interpret the function name instead of the string it contains.

Can you help me ? thanks !

Comment: but you have `myFunction` defined as a string.. `myfunction = "mySuperFunction";` ..

Comment: @Pogrindis OP is basically asking how to use the value of a variable as an object key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a create an empty object first, and then you can use array syntax to set it.

```
newCommand = {}; //empty object
speech = "my speech";
myfunction = "mySuperFunction";

newCommand[speech] = myfunction;

annyang.addCommands(newCommand);
```